# Where to ask: How to give evidence that an open-source project is reputable

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Other than having someone manually reading all of the code, how can you demonstrate an open-source project's reputability? IE, that it is not a virus/malware/whatever.  Where do I ask the preceding question on this site, if anywhere?

Comment: If you want to prove that using static code analysis, then the answer is that it's not possible in the general case. The [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) comes into play.

Comment: Note that, as I hinted at on MSO, the *audience* is going to be critical here - demonstrating *to other developers* is a very different game to demonstrating it *to non-technical managers*, for example. Have you considered talking to the people that are responsible for the decision and just **asking them what you could do?** Any external answer will be irrelevant if they don't accept it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe They want to look into it more, which is why I want help demonstrating that it's fine.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - your Code Golf mass closure IMHO should be discussed in a separate question. Same as for burnination, actually.

Comment: @DeerHunter I found it in the CV queue actually - someone else started it and I agreed with most of the CV's. You have a point though.

Answer (score 5):

Since you specifically mention Open Source, I suggest you try it on our new [Open Source SE site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com).

I should add that since that site is new, it may not remain on-topic there; the site is in beta, and still determining their scope.

Comment: +1 for cautious recommendation of new beta.